# Is it possible to build a sequence of positive real numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to build a sequence of positive real numbers $\{a_n\}$ such that 
$ $

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^2}< \infty \text{  and  } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}< \infty$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x_n=\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_n}}$. By the  Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have 
$$\left(\sum_1^\infty x_ny_n\right)^2\le \sum_1^\infty x_n^2 \sum_1^\infty y_n^2.$$
So if $\sum_1^\infty x_n^2$ and $\sum_1^\infty y_n^2$ converge, then $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ converges. But it does not.

Comment: @orangeskid: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I can´t see your idea...

Comment: What is it about the proof that causes difficulty? Using C-S, we show that if your two series both converged, then $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ would converge (or equivalently the partial sums $\sum_1^N \frac{1}{n}$ would be bounded). But they are not, so we cannot find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^2}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ both converge.